# MonoDroid: HelloWorld not ending up in Emulator

Tags: xamarin.android

I have installed MonoDroid and the hello world sample. I compile the app and choose the emulator from the selector. The app is compiled and pushed to the device from Visual Studio according to MonoDroid.

But it never appears in the emulator.

So, I tried to push the app up using ADB install

I get this error from adb:

Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by using the new Java 7 SDK.

Currently the only fix available is to uninstall Java 7 and install Java 6.

Comment: I uninstalled 7. It's building with 6, but still does not appear in the emulator:   Looking for Java SDK..
    Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\CurrentVersion found: 1.6.
    Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\1.6\JavaHome found:
      Path contains jarsigner.exe in \bin (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26).

Comment: Did you rebuild your application?  It won't re-sign it unless you make a change or choose rebuild.

Comment: Yes. I uninstalled everything, started clean with only 1.6. Deleted the bin and obj folders. Cleaned Solution. Created new AVD. THEN IT WORKED :) Hopefully some googler will see this and get help too.